# unexpected keyword argument 'coldStartStrategy' for ALS in Spark ml

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I found a couple of post where users are wondering why they are receiving `NaN` values in their predictions when using ALS. I ran into the same problem and seemingly found the answer and an implemented solution, with detailed discussion in the docs:

Note: there was a working link here to documentation on `coldStartStrategy()` however seemingly due to my question the documentation was removed.

Which I thought would solve the problem. Except even after updating to Spark 2.1.1 (wasn't working on 2.1.0) I am continuing to receive the same error:

TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'coldStartStrategy'

Here is where I attempt to use the argument:

```py
full_train, full_test = ugr_df.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3], seed=0L)
als = ALS(rank = rank, maxIter = maxIter, regParam = lmbda, 
          userCol = "user_id", itemCol="game_id", seed = seed, 
          ratingCol="rating", coldStartStrategy="drop")
optimized_model = als.fit(full_train)
```

I am importing ALS in this way:

```py
from pyspark.ml.recommendation import ALS
```

My code works fine when I take out the cold start argument. From what I can see in the docs, I am implementing it correctly.

- Is there a reason why the argument is not working correctly?
- If I am going to go without it can I safely do the following for the same effect? i.e. is the following code synonymous with the `coldStartStrategy` argument?

  ```py
  predictions = optimized_model.transform(full_test)
  predictions_drop = predictions.dropna()
  ```

Then go on to use the `predictions_drop` df for regression analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coldStartStrategy` has been introduced with SPARK-14489 in Spark 2.2, which hasn't been released yet:

- [Corresponding JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14489).
- [GitHub PR](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/b405466513bcc02cadf1477b6b682ace95d81658).

If you want to use it you have to build Spark from source or use developer builds.

Calling `na.drop` should have the same same effect as using `drop` strategy, which [internally it is implemented as](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d52f636228e833db89045bc7a0c17b72da13f138/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/recommendation/ALS.scala#L312-L313):

```
case ALSModel.Drop =>
  predictions.na.drop("all", Seq($(predictionCol)))
```